# How does "Hard Disk Protection" work in Sony Vaio?

Tags: hard-drive, sony-vaio

In `Vaio Control Center`, there is an option to enable `Hard Disc Protection`. Does anybody know how it works?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite a few brands have active protection these days - basically what active protection systems do is to park the hard drive in a safe place (or unloading the head) when the system is *falling* or has met some other source of sudden acceleration to prevent a head crash. The clever bit here is the use of of an accelerometer to sense these motions.

You *absolutely* want this enabled *unless* you have a SSD (in which case it is probably useless). It improves the chances of your hard drive surviving a drop quite a bit. For an SSD, its entirely useless, and probably won't help at all.

If you want to know more, wikipedia has a [fairly sparse article on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_hard-drive_protection), but its a reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the part "against impacts" I assume it is a very old thing that most hard drives do automatically these days: Move away the reading heads from the disk when not being used. That way external impacts-vibrations will not make the head hit the plates and damage them.

Answer (score 1):

> Advantages of VAIO HDD Protection.
>
> VAIO HDD Protection can detect and protect the hard disk of the VAIO computer. When the built-in 3D acceleration sensor detects any risk of drops or shocks, HDD-head will be shifted to secure position in order to avoid from scratching

[Source](http://www.sony.co.in/support/faq/147100)